# Run Scaffold DBContext without overwriting custom code in Entity Framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm using EF Core and DB First Approach. I generate my DBContext and entities class using `Scaffold-DbContext` and it gave me expected result, but when i run `Scaffold-DbContext` command again with `-Force`, it will overwrite my DBContext File

I'm using multitenant, and i have custom code inside DBContext file (new constructor, connection sting in OnConfiguring method)

how i can update my Models without overwrite DBContext File?

```
    public partial class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly ITenantDatabaseProvider _tenantProvider;

        public MyContext()
        {
        }

        public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public MyContext(ITenantDatabaseProvider tenantProvider)
        {
            _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_tenantProvider.GetTenantConnectionString().Result);
                //.AddInterceptors(new HintCommandInterceptor());
            }

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
        
    }
```

Comment: For this scenario, you should put your configuration outside of your generated DBContext. You have it declared as a partial class, so put your custom stuff in a separate partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While other answer tells to use different constructor, it does not explain how and why.

It is way cleaner to have db context separate from the concept of tenants, the only thing you need from your tenant is connection string? Well, you can pass it via options.

```
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}
```

To keep the same logic, use dynamic building of options for each db context instance

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationCoreDbContext>((services, builder) =>
{
    var tenantProvider = services.GetRequiredService<ITenantDatabaseProvider>();
    builder.UseSqlServer(tenantProvider.GetTenantConnectionString().Result);
});
```

Comment: how i can pass the connection string via options ? the file MyContext.cs will generated again and remove my changes  when i run `Scaffold-DbContext` later

Comment: `builder.UseSqlServer` in my snippet *is* passing connection string via options. dependency injection container uses options builder to create new instance of db context

Comment: this way you don't need `public MyContext(ITenantDatabaseProvider tenantProvider)` at all

Comment: `services.AddDbContext...` it's in Startup file , i need to change the connection with every request, i get the tenant (app id) from http headers

Comment: with scoped lifescope, this code in startup file will be executed per each request. actually not `AddDbContext` gets executed, but a lambda inside that constructs options

Comment: it's not working to me , not checked the tenant id from header to change the connection string

Comment: remove other constructors. Just tested. works perfectly for me. Also make sure `ITenantDatabaseProvider` has transient or scoped lifescope. And that you don't invoke `AddDbContext` with other settings

Comment: i have `services.AddTransient<ITenantDatabaseProvider, TenantDatabaseProvider>();` in startup , its not working ,  always get the connection string from `OnConfiguring` was generated by `Scaffold-DbContext`

Comment: my mistake ,to connect to database with tenant connection string i need to inject MyContext in controller, not use `MyContextdb = new MyContext()` ... thank you, its working